# can I access plex media server from the android app?

Tags: apt, beta, plex

I'm new to ubuntu and Linux. I have installed Plex using the ubuntu applications manager.

When I try to connect to the server using the android app in settings>library>New Library, It says I run a to old version of plex on Ubuntu, (it runs 0.7.x and requiers 0.8.x).

Can this be resolved somehow? Is there a stable beta I can run or something? How can it be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt did not have the latest version of plex in it's libraries. I added plex as a source and updated.